# Elastic search Analyse API response with error

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

I installed an Elastic Search Server (ES server), version 7.16.3, and I can't use (or play with) the analyse API mentioned here :

[Test an analyser](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/test-analyzer.html)

I've got the response:

```
{
    "error": "Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/_analyse] and method [POST], allowed: [HEAD, PUT, GET, DELETE]",
    "status": 405
}
```

with their first request :

```
POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "whitespace",
  "text":     "The quick brown fox."
}
```

How do I make their example working on my local ES server ?

Comment: Which tool you are using for the API request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct endpoint for `analyze` API is `localhost:9200/_analyze` not `localhost:9200/_analyse`, and you are using the wrong name in the endpoint which is causing the issue.

[image]

Comment: Your doc is wrong version.
If using GET I've got response : 

{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "request [GET /_analyse] does not support having a body"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "request [GET /_analyse] does not support having a body"
    },
    "status": 400
}

Comment: @FrançoisF., what do you mean by doc is wrong version?

Comment: @FrançoisF., i've always used both GET and POST API for `analyze` as asked earlier which tool you are using to make this call?

Comment: My version is not the latest, it is version 7.16.3, so the doc should be (cf. my link)

Comment: I use postman, make a POST request with : 
{{elserver}}/_analyse

Comment: `_analyze` is the correct name, can you change yours `_analyse` to it?

Comment: I don't understand, here my whole request URL used : http://localhost:9200/_analyse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244101/discussion-between-amit-and-francois-f).

Comment: Ok thanks _analyZe and not _analySe